# chart axis arrows are oversized when exported to pdf from report viewer

Tags: winforms, reportviewer, rdlc

I have this problem with the reportviewer pdf export. Everything is as simple as it can be, drag the chart run the report export to pdf you would expect it to work but it is not

create a new rdlc file and add a chart and modify it to have axis arrows

[image: rdlc design surface]

When viewed in report viewer everyhings fine

[image: report viewer]

Then i export this report to pdf but axis arrows are a bit oversized :)

[image: pdf export]

Any idea, help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance